# Use a OR wired with diodes to control the gate of a PMOSFET

Tags: mosfet

[image]If a have an OR wired with collector outputs to control the turn ON and turn OFF of a PMOSFET, shall I use a pull up resitor in the source input of the PMOSFET? Does the design need a pull down in the PMOSFET gate?

With this design the MOSFET is always turn ON, even when the gate is 5V, how is possible?

**UPDATE:**
I have replaced the input connected to the schottky diode by an open collector NPN and added a pull up between the source and the gate and a resistor in the input of the gate but the circuit doesn't work. The intention is to do a OR gate, so when one input is high the PMOSFET turns down.

[image]

Comment: *"With this design the MOSFET is always turn ON, even when the gate is 5V, how is possible?"* Because it is a P-channel mosfet. M2 is turned off (M2 is not conducting) when the gate voltage is 12V (with respect to ground). In that case \$V_{GS}=0V\$.

Comment: I think you should look again at the working of the P-channel mosfet. The circuit now drives M2 as were it a N-channel mosfet (but even then it's probably always on due to source V15)

Comment: Indeed, bring the PEMOS gate to 12v to turn **off** OUT1. Bring it to 0v to turn it on.  The gate has almost zero leakage resistance and current so acts like a small capacitor.  You may need a resistance to pull this to a "default" state when either of the OR inputs are not active.

Comment: For readers here who are interested in this topic: A [duplicate thread on edaboard.com is here](https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?385683-Use-an-OR-wired-with-diodes-to-control-the-gate-in-a-PMOSFET), and readers there are also giving answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the below. The comments indicate your problem- the gate must be allowed to rise to close to the +12V source voltage in order to completely turn the MOSFET off. This is done in the below circuit with an open-collector RTL NAND gate, with an inverter on one input, which I think preserves the logic you are trying to implement.

You could replace Q1-Q3 with 2N7000 or 2N7002 MOSFETs and eliminate R3 & R4, making it a bit simpler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foVc7I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>